# Passing variable from Scriptlet to javascript code.

Tags: java, javascript

I have this java code in jsp page ::

```
<%
String temp1;
PopulateTextbox obj = new PopulateTextbox();
temp1 = obj.method();
%>
```

And on the same jsp page i have javascript code ::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var storedata={
            identifier:"table1",
            label:"name",
            items: temp1
    };
    var gridStructure =[{
    cells:[
                [
                      { field: "ID",
                            name: "ID_Emp",
                            width: "40%", styles: 'text-align: right;'
                      },
                      {
                          field: "Names",
                          name: "Name",
                          width: "40%", styles: 'text-align: right;'
                      }

                ]
          ]
    }];
</script>
```

Now here temp1 is common. I want that the variable temp1 can be passed on to  or javascript code. how to do that ? thanks.

Comment: `var jsTempValue = "<%= temp1 %>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var storedata={
            identifier:"table1",
            label:"name",
            items: <%=temp1%>
            ...
```